# find end index of a regular expression search/match

Tags: javascript, regex

If I use string.match() with a regex, I'll get back the matched string, but not the index into the original string where the match occurs.  If I do string.search(), I get the index, but I don't necessarily know how long the matched part of the string is.  Is there a way to do both, so I can get the index of the ***end*** of the match in the original string?

I suppose I could do one after the other (below), assuming they return the same results but in a different way, but that seems ugly and inefficient, and I suspect there is a better way.

```
var str = "Fear leads to anger. Anger leads to hate. Hate leads to suffering"; 

var rgx = /l[aeiou]+d/i;
var match = str.match(rgx);
if (match && match[0]) {
  var i = str.search(rgx);
  console.log ("end of match is at index " + (i+match[0].length));
  }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.match` returns a new array with the following properties:

> The index property is set to the
>   position of the matched substring
>   within the complete string S.
>
> The input property is set to S.
>
> The length property is set to n +1.
>
> The 0 property is set to the matched
>   substring (i. e. the portion of S
>   between offset i inclusive and offset
>   e exclusive).
>
> For each integer i such that i >0 and i <= n, set the property named ToString(i) to the ith element of r's captures array.

From http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.10.6.2

`match.index` will provide what you need.

Comment: interesting....I had noticed that Chrome puts the index in the array (assuming you don't have a /g ....whereby there would be multiple matches and it wouldn't make sense to have a single index).  If this is supported by all reasonable browsers (...?), that's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
if (match && match[0]) {
    console.log ("end of match is at index " + (str.indexOf(match[0]) + match[0].length));
}
```

Comment: I guess you are right, that if you do an indexOf on match[0] it will always be the first occurance.  Unless there is a weird regular expression that might, say, give you the second occurance of a string...?